# Android : NFC APDU command response '6700' Wrong length'

Tags: android, command, nfc

I am sending below APDU command to ISODep tag and I am getting '6700 wrong length'

```
byte[] command = new byte[]{ (byte)0x80,  (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x07,(byte)0x22 , (byte)0x22,(byte)0x12 , (byte)0x34 , (byte)0x56 , (byte)0x78 , (byte)0x90  };
```

Please suggest if something is wrong in above command.

Comment: That's hard to answer without details of what kind of tag you're using.This is an application specific response. You could try adding an le byte `0x00` or `0xFF` and see if the response changes?

Comment: This question seems to bee too localized if you ask me. If the OP provides necessary detail, the question is not like to help anyone besides him

Comment: I am using MifareClassic tag type B. I tried with adding le by 0X00 but didn't get any success response , this time I got the 6d00.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [MifareClassic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html) tech instead of [IsoDep](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html) then?

Comment: I have to execute APDU command on this tag using IsoDep.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a case 4 APDU there, right? Your Lc indicates 0x07 bytes of data, and there's a Le of 0x90 trailing.
Check with your specification whether this command is actually expecting a case 4 structure, or whether you just got the data length in the Lc field wrong (0x08 instead of 0x07).