# '6985 Conditions of use not satisfied' while sending APDU command to javacard

Tags: javacard, apdu

I'm sending below command to javacard but I'm getting this error

Env: android app running on galaxy s3 over nfc

> 6985 Conditions of use not satisfied

It would be nice if you let me know what would be cause of this error.

```
byte[] APDU_Command = new byte[]{

                (byte)0x80,//CLA
                (byte)0xD0,//INS
                (byte)0x01,//P1
                (byte)0x00,//P2

                //Length
                (byte)0x21,//Lc

                //id
                (byte)31,
                (byte)32,
                (byte)33,
                (byte)34,

                //number
                (byte)33,                   
                (byte)35,
                (byte)31,
                (byte)36,
                (byte)39,                   
                (byte)38,
                (byte)30,    
                (byte)35,
                (byte)37,
                (byte)37,
                (byte)34,
                (byte)30,
                (byte)31,
                (byte)37,
                (byte)33,

                //Name
                (byte)50,
                (byte)72,
                (byte)65,
                (byte)76,
                (byte)61,
                (byte)73,
                (byte)54,
                (byte)65,
                (byte)73,
                (byte)74,
                (byte)43,
                (byte)61,
                (byte)72,
                (byte)64 

        };
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The highest bit (bit 8 in ISO 7816) is high, which means this is a non-standard APDU. We need to know at least the specification of the protocol to understand the returned status word (unless somebody guesses it from the given data).

Comment: That would be the leftmost bit of the CLA of course, the only one set when the byte has value `80` in hex.

Comment: Voted to close as "too localized" as the poster is unwilling to include more information, which makes this question impossible to answer, and the APDU is from a proprietary protocol.

Comment: No clue as to what protocol he's using. But if the id and number are supposed to be ASCII digits then he needs to send those values as hex (i.e. `0x31`, `0x32`, ...) instead of decimal (`30`, `31`, ...).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14850550/27190, which suggests the OP is trying to do Mifare Classic over ISO 7816 (some card readers may support APDUs for sending Mifare control commands).