# Different hex sting response from new device

Tags: java, android, hex, apdu, pcsc

Trying to change and existing android application which is reading data from a smart card using apdu command using wired smard reader to a ble device.

but the response for APDU command from each device looks different.

**Wired Reader:**

```
APDURequest HEX  = 00B00000
Response HEX = 6C27
```

**BLE Reader:**

```
APDURequest HEX  = 00B00000
Response HEX : 6985
```

checked with the card reader manufacturer weather the response is encrypted. but they are saying its plane hex string only.

Comment: Have you tried adding an Le byte to the command APDU (i.e. sending `00B0000000`)?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, 6985 Response mean conditions of use not satisfied' while sending APDU command to card.

[check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977039/6985-conditions-of-use-not-satisfied-while-sending-apdu-command-to-javacard)